# Solving a second order non-homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How do I solve the following non-homogeneous differential equation?

$$x^{2}y''+xy'=x^{2}\ln x$$ and $y(1)=2$, $y'(1)=0$.

I've started to solve the question in the following way,

Homogeneous equation is:

$$x^{2}y''+xy'=0\tag{2}$$

Let $x=e^{z}$ then $z=\log_e x=\ln x$

$$y'= \frac{dy}{dx} \quad\Rightarrow\quad \frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}\quad\Rightarrow\quad xy'=\frac{dy}{dz}=Du$$

Similarly,

$$x^{2}y''=D(D-1)y$$

Equation (2) becomes,
$${D(D-1)+D}y=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad (D^{2}-D+D)y=0\quad\Rightarrow \quad D^{2}y=0$$

Now I'm stuck for further process.

Comment: You need at least one solution to solve such ODE.

Comment: You can integrate $D^2y=0$ twice to get $y(z)=Az+B$

Comment: @Fakemistake I'm not sure if I'm fully understanding it. Then if for example if it's $(D-2)^{2}y=0$ then as it's a double solution $2, 2$ then it's $y(z)=Az+B$ too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformed ODE is $D^2y=ze^{2z}$

For the  solution of corresponding homogeneous equation the solution is $y_h=az+b=aIn(x)+b$ (Integrate $D^2y=0$ twice)

For the term $ze^{2z}$ in RHS, the particular solution is given as

$y_p= \frac {1}{D^2}ze^{2z}=\int\int ze^{2z}dz$ etc.

The general solution is $y(x)=y_h+y_p$. Can you proceed further?

Comment: should I first substitute the value of $z$ and process with the double integration and find out the particular solution?

Comment: Integrate directly without substitution as the operator $D=\frac{d}{dz}$.

Comment: Then the particular solution would be $\frac{(z-1)e^{2z}}{4}+C$

Comment: It would be $\frac{(z-1)e^{2z}}{4}=\frac{x^2.(In(x)-1)}{4}$. Drop the integration constant $c$ as it is not a general solution.

Comment: I think I got the answer. $a=\frac{1}{4}$ and $b=\frac{9}{4}$. I will replace the calculated values onto the general solution.

I had some questions about how did you get the transformed ODE for $D^{2}y$ and the homogeneous equation is as $az+b$ due to $D=0(twice)$?

Comment: $D^(az+b)=0\implies y=az+b$ where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants of the one degree polynomial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106551/discussion-between-santi-and-nitin-uniyal).

Comment: You can accept my answer if it fulfils your query by making the tick green.

Comment: May I ask you some questions through the above chat?

Comment: I am using android application of MSE on my mobile. May be that's why chat box not opening.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm fully understanding it the explanation you gave me. Then if for example if it's $(D−2)2y=0$ then as it's a double solution $2,2$ then it's $y(z)=Az+B$ too?

Comment: For $(D-a)^2y=0$ then roots of auxiliary equation i.e. $(m-2)^2=0$ will be $2,2$. Then $y_h=(a+bz)e^{2z}$.

Comment: Reading your explanation, I had another question. We do the double integration due to $\frac{1}{D^{2}}$?

Comment: You can ask this as a separate question though for details. However $1/D^k$ stands for integration $k$ times.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2y''+xy'=x^2\ln(x)$$
Why don't you simplify ?
$$xy''+y'=x\ln(x)$$
$$(xy')'=x\ln(x)$$
Integrate :
$$xy'=\frac12 x^2\ln(x)-\frac14 x^2+c_1$$
Condition : $y'(1)=0\quad\implies\quad 0=-\frac14+c_1\quad\implies\quad c_1=\frac14$
$$y'=\frac12 x\ln(x)-\frac14 x+\frac{1}{4x}$$
Integrate :
$$y=\frac14 x^2\ln(x)-\frac14 x^2+\frac14 \ln(x)+c_2$$
Condition : $y(1)=2\quad\implies\quad 2=-\frac14 +c_2\quad\implies\quad c_2=\frac94$
$$y=\frac14 x^2\ln(x)-\frac14 x^2+\frac14 \ln(x)+\frac94$$